# Oracle PL/SQL Query, Adding new column through looping

Tags: sql, oracle, loops

I have a table in excel which is called the test table:

[image]

I need to create an additional column called level in the table through the following steps.

1. Whenever 'parent' column is equal to 'EEP', Check the values in the location column.  In this table, the location column has only A under the filter of EEP for parent column. Now Assign value of 1 in the level column
2. Now check value  A under parent column. Values under location are B,N,S. Assign 2 under level column
3. Now check B,N,S under parent column. Values under location are C,D,Q,U,V. Assign 3 under level column
4. Now check C,D,Q,U,V under parent column. values corresponding to location are R, M. Assign 4 under level column.

My final table should look something like this.

[image]

I need to write a query in Oracle SQL to do the same for all rows in the parent column adding one in the level column after every iteration. This data is just a test data, the original data has more than 2.6 million rows.

Answer (score 0):

You need a simple connect by clause -

```
CREATE TABLE NEW_TABLE AS
SELECT C.LOCATION, C.PARENT, LEVEL
FROM CTE C
START WITH PARENT = 'EEP'
CONNECT BY PRIOR LOCATION = PARENT;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2b492de9d7e83bfe923356e332810d41) is the fiddle

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. Can you tell me how can I save this as a new table and export as excel in the same code?

Comment: Trying to do this using simple CREATE Table function is throwing an error which says 'ORA-00998: must name this expression with a column alias'

Comment: For creating a new column, I have updated the code but for exporting to excel you have to take some other methods.